# I can't install xde expo on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, react-native, expo, ubuntu-18.04

I can't install xde expo on Ubuntu
my OS Ubuntu 18.04 lts & node -v 10.16.3 and npm -v 6.9.0
I try install it by this command line
`npm install -g expo-cli`
but when I write 
`expo -v` or
`expo --v`or 
`expo --version`
I get the same result

```
  command 'exo' from snap exoscale-cli (v1.5.1)
  command 'expr' from deb coreutils
  command 'exp' from deb alliance
  command 'expn' from deb sendmail-base
```

please any help 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
sudo npm i expo-cli --unsafe-perm=true
```

Comment: I try that command but that not successful  I get

```
+ expo-cli@3.3.0
added 1300 packages from 856 contributors and audited 29331 packages in 521.207s
found 20 vulnerabilities (1 moderate, 19 high)
```

Comment: did  you try 'npm audit fix'    and try again

Comment: I got 
```
npm ERR! code EAUDITNOPJSON
npm ERR! audit No package.json found: Cannot audit a project without a package.json

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-10-10T17_13_35_089Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Try npm -g uninstall expo-cli --save and after sudo npm i expo-cli --unsafe-perm=true

Comment: I try it but not successful so I take screen shoot
https://suar.me/reLg9

Comment: Last one: try to install with yarn: yarn global add expo-cli

Comment: You have to install yarn before: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#debian-stable

Comment: Thank you I solved just write `npm install -g expo-cli` I don't know why it is run but I think this commend line `npm -g uninstall expo-cli --save` fix any issue

Comment: My expo -version 3.3.0 but I can't access at xde I don't know why
can you help me?

Comment: No I haven't any error but I don't know how can I open xde on my OS

Answer (score 0):

**The xde Is deprecated Now** 
[Create a new app](https://docs.expo.io/get-started/create-a-new-app/)